# Big O Notation Clarification

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

Working through a textbook on algorithms (CLRS intro to algorithms) and just wanted to see if someone could help me understand one of the exercises at the end of a chapter.

Problem:
Is $n^{2 + 1} = O(n^2)$?

The book uses = loosely to convey the "set of" notation, so it's more like "is $n^{2 + 1}$ contained within $O(n^2)$"? The solutions set says it holds true, but my thought was that the $n+1$ term would mean that it should contain $n^2$ instead. Do we drop the constant even in exponents?

Comment: Do you mean $ n^2 + 1 $ or $ n ^{2 + 1} $ ?

Comment: Whoops -- first post on this SE site. $ n ^{2+1} $

Comment: I have edited your post, is this what it should look like?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: So you're asking if $n^3=O(n^2)$? Certainly not.

Comment: That's what I thought! Might have to double check again to make sure my eyes aren't playing tricks on me